# Bubble up selection in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to pass the current selection in my react-table component up to the parent to do some logic when a selection has occurred, but I can't seem to find a way to reliably get the selection. I've tried the following:

```
function Table({ columns: userColumns, data, setSelection }) {
  const {
      ...,
      selectedFlatRows,
    } = useTable(
      {
        ...
      },
       ...,
      useRowSelect,
      (hooks) => {...})

  useEffect(() => {

      // Bubble up the selection to the parent component
      setSelection(selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original));
   }, [selectedFlatRows]);
```

But the above just creates an infinite loop. I've built the table selection based on the guidance [given in the docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection), but they dont seem to cover how to get the selected row reliably.

Comment: you have the function, `setSelection` do you have the state `selection`?  A codesandbox to reproduce would be helpful.

Comment: Its important to know how TableComponent is rendered and what setSelection modifies i n the parent

Comment: I have same issue, How did you solve it?

set selection will end up in an infinite loop

Comment: @HarishKulkarni see my answer below

Comment: Thanks, I used useCallback & table.options.autoresetpage to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst rotimi-best's answer is correct, it didn't solve my issue. I had a containing function component which needed to know about the selection. My structure was as follows:

```
<Container> // This container needs to know about the selection.
   <Table
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      setSelection={(selection) => handleSetSelection(selection)} // Passed down to the table instance
   />
</Container>
```

The solution was to wrap the top level `setSelection` in a useCallback. This, together with using memoization as outlined by the react-table docs solved the issue.

```
Container:
...
const [selection, setSelection] = useState([]);
const selectionCallback = React.useCallback((ids) => setSelection(ids), [
    setSelection,
  ]);
```

Comment: Chris could you please elaborate even i am facing infinite loop issue

Answer (score 2):

I don't get an infinite loop. The sandbox doc you mentioned in your question, I implemented what you requested and every thing worked well. Please take a look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-joliot-octgc?file=/src/App.js) and the short snippet I took from the sandbox.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable, useRowSelect } from 'react-table'

import makeData from './makeData'

function Table({ columns, data, setSelection }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    selectedFlatRows,
    state: { selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useRowSelect,
    hooks => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: 'selection',
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ])
    }
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Bubble up the selection to the parent component
    setSelection(selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original));
  }, [setSelection, selectedFlatRows]);

  console.log('selectedFlatRows', selectedFlatRows)

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          data here
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([]);
  const columns = []

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(10, 3), [])
  console.log('selection', selection)
  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} setSelection={setSelection} />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I found a similar solution with global store `useEffect(() => { if (isSelectable && selectedFlatRows) { const rows = selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original); context.dispatch({ action: "selectedFlatRows", data: rows }); } }, [selectedFlatRows]);` I don't get the use of `setSelection` as a dependency and how it affects things there, shouldn't be `selection`?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above (or anywhere else on the interwebs) worked for me but here's what did. And I imagine, with the number of people who've asked this same question about React Table v7, that in version 8 of React Table, the state, especially state having to do with selection, has been ironed out. But anyway this is the ONLY workaround that worked for me, loosely based on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/tannerlinsleyreact-table-row-selection-controlled-euyku?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

// Parent component

1. I used a `useCallback` hook to prevent my `setSelectedRows` (your `setSelection`) function being passed to the child as a new function and kicking off multiple renders.
2. And I passed in an initial state that sets React Table's `selectedRowIds` with the parent's `selectedRows`:

```
const ParentDoingParentyThings = () => {
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState({});
  const handleSelection = React.useCallback((value) => {
    setSelectedRows(value);   
    }, []); 

return (
  <Table
        data={tableData}
        setSelectedRows={handleSelection}
        initialState={{ sortBy: [{ id: 'totalSeries', desc: true }], selectedRowIds: selectedRows }}
        ...
      />
  )
}
```

// And the Table / child
Then!...

1. I use this lesser know function from React Table called `useMountedLayoutEffect`. Dont ask me in detail what it does, but it works, that's what it does....
2. Then I pull from RT's `selectedRowIds` state
3. And I use RT's `useMountedLayoutEffect` function like I would a `useEffect`

```
import {
  ...
  useMountedLayoutEffect,
} from 'react-table';

export const Table = ({
  data,
  setSelectedRows,
  initialState,
  ...
}: Props) => {
  ...
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state: { selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      data: tableData,
      initialState,
      ...
    },
    useSortBy,
    useRowSelect,
  );

  useMountedLayoutEffect(() => {
    setSelectedRows && setSelectedRows(selectedRowIds);
  }, [setSelectedRows, selectedRowIds]);

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()} className={className}>
      ...
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define columns and/or your data with React.useMemo to avoid infinite loop.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: 'Column 1',
      accessor: 'col1', // accessor is the "key" in the data
    },
    {
      Header: 'Column 2',
      accessor: 'col2',
    },
  ],
  []
)
```